# Outlook: add a specific word to be highlighted as an error

Tags: microsoft-outlook, highlighting, dictionary, autocorrect

When writing a mail, I am used to misspell the name of a colleague, I therefore would like to have an error Highlight, when writing wrong.

Do you know how to add a specific word to be highlighted as an error when typed?

**Note:** I Don't want to make an autocorrect but rather an error Highlight.

**Example:** the name is Philipp (correct) that I am used to write Philip (wrong). In the picture bellow we can see 'Philip' is not highlighted even though it is also not part of my custom dictionary, Any help to make it highlighted?[image: picture example]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is quite easy. You need to add Philip to the exclusion list. Open the *%AppData%\Microsoft\UProof* directory and edit the ExcludeDictionary[LANG][LCID].lex file with Notepad (where LANG is a language and LCID is a locale ID). See here for a full list of locale IDs: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc233982.aspx. For US English, the name of the file would be **ExcludeDictionaryEN0409.lex**. It contains one word per line, just add the "Philip" there (without quotes) and restart Outlook/Word/...

Comment: Just what I was looking for, Thanks a lot Thims!